# Is there an alternative for TKinter open file dialog box?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I am making a small 2d game engine using pygame and I want to open the file dialog box. The only option I can find is tkinter, and when I run this code

```
root = Tk()
*code here*
filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/", title="Select A File",
                                                      filetypes=(
                                                          ("Png Files", "*.png"), ("Jpg Files", "*.jpg"))).name
*code here*
root.mainloop()
```

everything is working as expected except the fact that another white GUI is opening, so I deleted the `mainloop()` and `root = Tk()` lines but it gives me an error

The error is this:

```
pygame 2.0.0.dev8 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.8.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
2020-11-27 22:04:14.676 Python[3271:272456] -[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ee3438be0
2020-11-27 22:04:14.679 Python[3271:272456] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ee3438be0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204b66af __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201ee3c9 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20538c85 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2041e06d ___forwarding___ + 1467
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2041da28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010adb21f2 TkpInit + 408
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010ad21aac Initialize + 2454
    7   _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x000000010ab75714 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    8   _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x000000010ab75032 _tkinter_create + 1362
    9   Python                              0x0000000109dc890f cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 175
    10  Python                              0x0000000109e5a93c call_function + 444
    11  Python                              0x0000000109e5779e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    12  Python                              0x0000000109e5b784 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    13  Python                              0x0000000109d8cace _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    14  Python                              0x0000000109d8be37 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    15  Python                              0x0000000109d8d43f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    16  Python                              0x0000000109de3631 slot_tp_init + 145
    17  Python                              0x0000000109ddea79 type_call + 297
    18  Python                              0x0000000109d8bfe5 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    19  Python                              0x0000000109e5a995 call_function + 533
    20  Python                              0x0000000109e57835 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25829
    21  Python                              0x0000000109d8c930 function_code_fastcall + 128
    22  Python                              0x0000000109e5a93c call_function + 444
    23  Python                              0x0000000109e5779e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    24  Python                              0x0000000109e5b784 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    25  Python                              0x0000000109d8cace _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    26  Python                              0x0000000109e5a93c call_function + 444
    27  Python                              0x0000000109e5779e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    28  Python                              0x0000000109e5b784 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    29  Python                              0x0000000109d8cace _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    30  Python                              0x0000000109d8be37 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    31  Python                              0x0000000109d8d43f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    32  Python                              0x0000000109de3631 slot_tp_init + 145
    33  Python                              0x0000000109ddea79 type_call + 297
    34  Python                              0x0000000109d8bfe5 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    35  Python                              0x0000000109e5a995 call_function + 533
    36  Python                              0x0000000109e57835 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25829
    37  Python                              0x0000000109e5b784 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    38  Python                              0x0000000109d8cace _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    39  Python                              0x0000000109e5a93c call_function + 444
    40  Python                              0x0000000109e5777a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    41  Python                              0x0000000109e5b784 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    42  Python                              0x0000000109d8cace _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    43  Python                              0x0000000109e5a93c call_function + 444
    44  Python                              0x0000000109e578c8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25976
    45  Python                              0x0000000109e5b784 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    46  Python                              0x0000000109e51274 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
    47  Python                              0x0000000109ea0ee0 PyRun_FileExFlags + 336
    48  Python                              0x0000000109ea05d0 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 864
    49  Python                              0x0000000109ebdae3 Py_RunMain + 2179
    50  Python                              0x0000000109ebde3f pymain_main + 223
    51  Python                              0x0000000109ebe03b Py_BytesMain + 43
    52  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2035f631 start + 1
    53  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Thank you!

(If there is anything wrong with this question it would be *HIGHLY* reccomended to type it in the comments so I can edit this and make it more user friendly)

Comment: Are you importing pygame? And if so are you using it elsewhere in the code?

Comment: yeah, i just ommited that part since its the basics, im doing it all fine.

Comment: Weird... It's as if pygame is interfering with tkinter

Comment: it is, cause i have a pygame GUI open, and when i call root = Tk() it's making another GUI so i deleted root = Tk() and now the opening of dialog box isnt working.

Comment: pypi.org/project/easygui  --  easygui is easy to figure out  --  https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#working-with-files

Comment: Maybe there's a function in pygame to open a file...

Comment: Oh thankyou! @Doyousketch, do i have to open another blank GUI to run that though...?

Comment: @Kettle3D ill check, if it doesnt work then ill go with easygui.

Comment: That's a good idea.

Comment: easygui doesnt work either

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import easygui as g

title = 'Choose your destiny'
filename = g.fileopenbox( title )

file = open( filename )
```

Python has the ability to open files, it's literally just `file = open('filename.ext')`  *But pygame doesn't do filesystem traversal for you.*

So you'd need to either find a library that can print out the contents of a directory, plus allow you make a selection from that list, or make one.  EasyGUI simplifies that process, 'cuz you don't have to hunting for solutions, when it's right there.

*Run this bit of code without pygame involved at all,* so you can see what it does.  If it gives you a dialog, and returns the file, then you're good to go.  Just initialize pygame from that point, and begin from there.

Comment: I'm certain pygame can load files, otherwise you couldn't run games with sound or graphics, *but there's no built-in menu for it.*  You'd need to find some sorta lib for that, or build your own.  This just happens to be quick.  Is it something you can load before the game gets running?  That seems like the best way to do it.